# Two finger scrolling and other multitouch gestures are not working on asus laptop model x555u.

Tags: touchpad, asus, scrolling, gestures

Output of xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of synclient -l

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

uname -r

```
4.2.0-19-generic
```

Comment: Try this first `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Then tell the output of `synclient`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already installed. No change in output of synclient.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on an Asus ux501vw by installing kernel 4.3.3 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.3-040303-generic_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.3-040303_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.3-wily/linux-image-4.3.3-040303-generic_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3.3-040303_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_all.deb linux-headers-4.3.3-040303-generic_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_amd64.deb linux-image-4.3.3-040303-generic_4.3.3-040303.201512150130_amd64.deb
sudo reboot
```